# Node.js: Defining Postgres Schemas in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

The [Official Documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/schema/) doesn't explains clearly how define schemas for database by themselves. I'm assuming that Sequelize is more related to MySql than Postgres (where schemas are mandatory).

If I've already created some schemas in Postgres, how I could sync them with Sequelize?

Comment: I think you need to recreate the models using sequelize before you can sync. There was a project I saw that generated models from an existing db (SQL Server(?)) but it didn't work very well for me.

Comment: I can recreate the models (tables) perfectly with Sequelize. My issue are the Postgres Schemas (public, security, audit, whatever...), that I've created in Postgres. These schemas will contain the models (tables), but for themselves I don't know how sync them with Sequelize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the model with the schema using `model.schema`, something like:

```
var City = sequelize.define('City', {
    id: {
        type: sequelize.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        field: 'id'
    },
    name: {
        type: sequelize.Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'name'   
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'cities'
    });
City.schema("public");
```

Comment: I think you meant City.schema("public")

Comment: I figured but JavaScript doesn't know that!

Comment: Thank you so much! It is just all want!

Comment: And also, this answer is valid to me: stackoverflow.com/a/32025860/6291719

Comment: Nice, this is the way

Comment: is it possible to set schema for all models at once at connection time?

Comment: Answer for the above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070444/how-can-i-set-schema-for-all-models-at-once-at-connection-time-for-sequelize-pos