# How can I set schema for all models at once at connection time for Sequelize Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm able to set schema for ad-hock queries with

```
sequelize.query(`
    SET SCHEMA 'schema_for_client_name'
`);
```

I'm also able to set schema for individual models

```
User.init(
    {
      userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      salt: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      tableName: 'users',
      schema: 'schema_for_client_name',
      timestamps: false,
    }
);
```

Is it possible to set schema for all models at once at connection time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-constructor-constructor) the `Sequelize` constructor takes an optional default `schema` option:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {schema: 'schema_for_client_name'});
```